# clone : the use of the function : php

Tags: php

can someone give me a diffrenet definition of the function and maybe some examples? i really dont get it. what is it suppose to do?

```
<?php

    class Foo
    {
        var $that;

        function __clone()
        {
            $this->that = clone $this->that;
        }

    }

    $a = new Foo;
    $b = new Foo;
    $a->that = $b;
    $b->that = $a;

    $c = clone $a;
    echo 'What happened?';
    var_dump($c);
?>
```

i really cant understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo // a class, it represents a real object normally
{
    var $that; //field called $that of class Foo

    function __clone() //In this SPECIAL case it overrides the normal clone function and what follows below is a custom body for this function
    {
        $this->that = clone $this->that; //set the field of this object (created from Foo) to a clone of that field. In other words force to point to a copy
    } //end of fucntion declaration

} //end of class declaration

$a = new Foo; //create object $a from class Foo
$b = new Foo; //create object $b from class Foo
$a->that = $b; //set $that property of object $a to point to $b
$b->that = $a; //set $that property of object $b to point to $a

$c = clone $a; // create a clone of $a and put it in variable $c CREATES AN ERROR!
echo 'What happened?'; //echo string litteral

var_dump($b); // I added this because:
/*
 *  *RECURSION* will occur (also if you dump $a)
 *   the output is:
```

> object(Foo)#2 (1) { ["that"]=> object(Foo)#1 (1) { ["that"]=>
>   *RECURSION* } }

```
 */
var_dump($c); //print out object $c
```

You have a circular reference now

To understand better what `clone` does I suggest you read http://jacob-walker.com/blog/php-clone-and-shallow-vs-deep-copying.html